# undefined method 'post' for Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, saas

I'm working through a tutorial on Cucumber and Rspec for RoR in the textbook Engineering Software as a Service, along with going through the archived course on edX.org. I've run into a problem trying to work with Rspec.  The index view has a form which posts to a controller method, with the sole field having the name :search_terms. In movies_controller.rb has this method:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def search_tmdb
    @movies = Movie.find_in_tmdb(params[:search_terms])
    flash[:notice] = "Movie '#{params[:search_terms]}' not found."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end
```

In movies_controller_spec.rb is the following:

```
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe MoviesController do
    describe 'searching TMDb' do
      it 'should call the model method that performs TMDb search' do
        post :search_tmdb, {:search_terms => 'hardware'}
      end
      ...
    end
  end
```

Rspec gives me the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xb36c92c>
```

It's my understanding that 'post' is a method that Rspec is supposed to provide inside the 'it' block, to simulate the posting of a form. I've searched but haven't found anything on point. One suggestion I found suggested that a user correct model class inheritance, but I don't have models yet, and I've seen this code work, or at least provide a helpful error message, on a screencast, without a model being implemented. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDITED

Here is my 'spec_helper' file

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"
```

end

Comment: What's in your spec helper?

Comment: can you please post the code in spec/spec_helper.rb file?

Answer (score 5):

With the most recent versions of RSpec Rails there are two files made available for running specs

`spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb`

It is likely that you need to use `require 'rails_helper'` to make the `post` method available.

Hope this helps

Comment: I added "require 'rails_helper'" to my spec_helper file and ran bundle exec rspec, and get a load error.  The error is /gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)    Although this course ended in late May, and I'm running on the course virtual machine, it uses Rails 3.2. I'm wondering if there are some issues stemming from that.

Comment: Found the problem. Embarrassingly, while I had created the spec/controllers folder, I had saved the movies_controller_spec file in the spec folder. Moving it to the controllers folder resolved the issue. Sorry for the trouble, thanks for your help.